# How to send an alert

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do you code an alert message in objective c. Xcode if the user chooses the wrong color in the application.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) is a wonderful thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) class. Here's an example:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Wrong Color"
                      message: @"You chose the wrong color."
                      delegate: nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
            message: @"You chose the wrong color!"
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).